# Null Pointer Exception when running loop in GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to find the list of children of node, but every time I pass the node I am getting `NullPointerException`

```
<g:each in="${nodes}" var="node">
   <g:if test="${node.parent == null }">

      ${node.id }-${node.label }   //This works perfectly 

      <g:each in="${Node.findAllByParent(node)}" var="n">
            ${n.label}
      </g:each> 
   </g:if>
</g:each>
```

The class looks like:

```
class Node {       
    String nodeId
    String label    
    Node parent    
}
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the method `findAllByParent` on null object, even though the node does contain some information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that `Node` is in a package and if it is you either need to add an import to the top of the GSP...

```
<% import com.mypackage.Node %>
```

Or fully qualify the reference...

```
<g:each in="${com.mypackage.Node.findAllByParent(node)}" var="n">
```

You really shouldn't be initiating the query from a GSP to begin with, but that is a separate issue.  One of the above should make your error go away.

Comment: The issue is that when the compiler sees `Node`, without an import statement that looks like a variable reference.  Since the `Node` variable hasn't been initialized, it will be null so you are invoking `findAllByParent` on a null reference.  If you fully qualify the class name or add an import, then the compiler will know that `Node` is not a variable reference but instead is a `Class` reference.